# JavaScript timer stops working when time left is less than 1 day

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a simple JS timer, I tried this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmjpMW

It's good but, if I change

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

to

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 0 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Which translates to 0 Days, 24 Hours, 60 Mins and 60 Seconds. (So if there's less than a day remaining) The timer stops working and display `-1 Days, -1 Hours, -1 Mins, -1 Seconds`

I can't figure out whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, that's not what it translates to. You changed "15 multiples of 24 multiples of 60 multiples of 60 multiples of 1000", which is "15 days", to 0 such multiples.

Comment: But you do realise that `0 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is equal to zero, right?

Comment: Remove `0 *` from the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are not 0 days and 24 hours.

You're essentially setting the deadline to the current time, i.e. telling the timer "deadline is right now" since

```
0 * x = 0
```

An obvious solution would be to remove the multiplication by 0 at all, leaving just `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.